Is the Canadian capital cost allowance applicable in the year an asset is sold?
My company sold an asset near the end of the year. Can I claim CCA for the portion of the year the asset was in use? Based on my understanding of Schedule 8 Part 2 Note 18 and 19, this does not seems possible.

How would that make sense? You claim gain/loss on the sale the same year.

I am asking if you can expense part of the gain as CCA since the asset was in use for most of the year.

What's the point? It would be immediately recaptured. See here.

@littleadv thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I did some reading and now understand that terminal loss is treated as an expense and not a capital loss. Makes sense now. Feel free to create an answer and I will accept. Thanks again.
